# Can I use CRC Dry Graphite Lube for Car Door Lock?

Tags: car, locks

It comes in an aerosol can and WITHOUT a straw to fit into the lock slit, which surprised me enough that I was looking into returning it. I can spray it on the key and get at least some of the stuff in there, but maybe some of you have better suggestions? I bought the stuff because some online site recommended it for the purpose of lubing a car door lock. It kind of seems useless without a straw. Does anyone agree on this point?

Comment: " It kind of seems useless without a straw. Does anyone agree on this point?" Yes I do. You can hold the lock cover open with a paperclip or other suitable device, then spray the aerosol into the lock.

Comment: Hey, we need to keep the paper clip makers in business....

Answer (score 1):

Bathing the key in the stuff, akin to spray painting it and then inserting and removing the key from the lock will transfer a respectable amount of lube to the lock's workings. Repeat the process multiple times for even more transfer.

Dry graphite is the best material for a lock, as it will not freeze in cold weather and remains fluid (not liquid) within the mechanism.

I have a handful of straws about the shop, but I suspect that's not the case for you.